# MySQL server has gone away while running Laravel Queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I am trying to import data from CSV file to database using laravel queue. These CSV files are huge with around 500k number of rows.

I have learned somewhere that using laravel queue we don't need to think about connection time out but this is not looking true. Maybe I was wrong.

Please, check my job code if there is anything wrong in these methods. I am using "League\Csv" to read the CSV file.

```
public function __construct($data,$error_arr,$error_row_numbers) {  
       $this->data = $data;
       $this->error_arr = $error_arr;
       $this->error_row_numbers = $error_row_numbers;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $offset = $this->data['offset']; 
        $limit = $this->data['limit'];

        $filename = $this->data['file_name'];
        $service = new Service();
        $table = 'committees';
        $dbase = new Committee();

        //map_data have array about which csv column
        //should be inserted in which column of database
        $map_data = $this->data['map_data'];

    //get all columns name of a table
        $db_header_obj = new Committee();
        $db_header = $db_header_obj->getTableColumns();

        $csv_file_path = storage_path('app/files/committee/').$filename;
        if (!ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
            ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", TRUE);
        }
        $csv = Reader::createFromPath($csv_file_path, 'r');

        $csv->setOutputBOM(Reader::BOM_UTF8);
        $csv->addStreamFilter('convert.iconv.ISO-8859-15/UTF-8');

            $csv->setHeaderOffset(0); 
            $csv_header = $csv->getHeader();    



            $rec_arr = array();
            $records = array();
            $records_arr = array();

                    $stmt = (new Statement())
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ;

                    $records = $stmt->process($csv);

                    foreach ($records as $record) 
                    {
                        $rec_arr[] = array_values($record);
                    }

                    //trim index if the value of an array is empty
                    $records_arr = $service->trimArray($rec_arr);

                    if(count($records_arr)>0)
                    {
                        foreach($records_arr as $ck => $cv){


                            $committee_arr = array();
                            foreach ($map_data as $mk => $mv) {
                                if(isset($mv)){
                                    $data_type = $service->getDatabaseColumnType($table,$mv);
                                    //if data is one of datetime data type
                                    //then format the csv data to mysql datetime format
                                    if($data_type == 'date' || $data_type == 'datetime' || $data_type == 'timestamp'){
                                        $datetime =  (array)$cv[$mk];
                                        $dt = array_shift($datetime);
                                        $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($dt));
                                        $committee_arr[$mv] = $dt;
                                    }else{
                                        $committee_arr[$mv] = $cv[$mk];
                                    }  

                                }
                            }

                            $error_encountered = false;


                            DB::beginTransaction();

                            if(!empty($committee_arr['com_id'])){

                                try{
                                        $committee_row = Committee::updateOrCreate(
                                            ['com_id' => $committee_arr['com_id']],
                                            $committee_arr
                                        );
                                        if ($committee_row->wasRecentlyCreated === true) {
                                            $committee_row->created_by = $this->data['user_id'];
                                        }else{
                                            $committee_row->updated_by = $this->data['user_id'];
                                        }
                                        $committee_row->save();
                                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                                        $error_encountered = true;
                                         $this->error_arr[] = $e->getMessage();
                                         $this->error_row_numbers[] = $this->data['row_value']; 
                                    }

                            }


                            DB::commit();
                            //just to keep track which row is currently processing
                            //so that user can be notified in which row of csv
                            //there is an error
                            $this->data['row_value'] = $this->data['row_value'] + 1;

                        }

                        //offset just to start fectch next chunk of data from csv
                        $this->data['offset'] = $offset + $limit;

            //Call to same job but with increased offset value
                        $committeeInsertJob = (new StoreCommittee($this->data,$this->error_arr,$this->error_row_numbers))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3)); 
                        dispatch($committeeInsertJob);

                    }else{

                        //Store activity just to keep track of activity
                        $activity = new Activity();
                        $activity->url = $this->data['url'];
                        $activity->action = 'store';
                        $activity->description = $table;
                        $activity->user_id = $this->data['user_id'];
                        $activity->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        $activity->save();

                        $arr_data = [
                                'filename' => $filename,
                                'user_name' => $this->data['user_name'],
                                'error' => $this->error_arr,
                                'error_row_numbers' => $this->error_row_numbers
                            ];
                        //Notify user that the job is complete
                        Mail::to($this->data['user_email'])->send(new CSVImportJobComplete($arr_data));

                    }



            if (!ini_get("auto_detect_line_endings")) {
                ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", FALSE);
            }
        }
```

Error: From (laravel.log inside storage)

```
[2019-04-05 07:13:23] local.ERROR: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`) values (default, 0, , 1554448406, 1554448403, ....................................................(long list)
```

From: command terminal

```
$ php artisan queue:work --tries=3
[2019-04-05 07:09:11][1] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:09:33][1] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:09:36][2] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:09:58][2] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:10:01][3] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:10:23][3] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:10:26][4] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:10:48][4] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:10:51][5] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:11:13][5] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:11:17][6] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:11:40][6] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:11:43][7] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:12:05][7] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:12:08][8] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:12:31][8] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:12:34][9] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:12:57][9] Processed:  App\Jobs\StoreCommittee
[2019-04-05 07:13:00][10] Processing: App\Jobs\StoreCommittee

dell@DESKTOP-UQ2 MINGW64 /d/wamp64/www/project(master)
$
(it stops without any error or failed notifications)
```

Is there anything I can improve on my job logic? How can I handle all this connection drop, or maxed timed out or some other stuff? I don't think the increasing timeout is the solution. As it can't be guaranteed that it will be finished within this fixed time.

Instead is there a way, were connection can be closed and again reconnect between each queue working?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a single query to squeeze all 500k records in MySQL. Is that true? If yes, the approach is completely wrong. You should prepare the statement once, for inserting a single record. In a loop, you bind values and execute the statement. You also have a transaction there but only 1 query is being executed from what I can tell. That means transaction is pointless because if you have only 1 query - InnoDB runs in autocommit mode (every query is its own transaction).

Comment: @mjh currently I am using chunk of 250 rows, this means this loop `foreach($records_arr as $ck => $cv){` will run 250 times and then later call same job with offset value of 250. Could you suggest, any other way, if this is not suitable for this?

Answer (score 2):

### Attempted solution

You parsed the CSV file and you tried to send entire contents via a single query. MySQL contains variables that prevent it from accepting too large queries. It's called [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html)

Reason why you did that was performance. However, you can hit one of many variables related to networking / MySQL when dealing with a query that's too large in regards to data quantity.

### Improved solution criteria

- Clean query so it's visible what's being done
- Fast query, so a lot of data can be sent to make writes fast
- Don't hit the values of limiting variables such as max_packet_size

### Solution

1. Prepared the statement exactly once. Prepared statements are used once, executed multiple times
2. Parse the CSV and loop through records
3. Bind values to the prepared statements and execute it as you're going through the loop
4. To make everything faster, use transactions. Wrap every 1000 records in a transaction.  That will let you write simple insert queries but they'll be fast because MySQL will multiplex the writes

You're using Laravel so steps above are super-easy

### Pseudo Code using laravel

```
$csv = collect([]); // This is the array holding your CSV records

// Split the array into chunks. Let's assume you want to insert 1000 records in one attempt

$chunk_count = ceil($csv->count() / 1000);

$csv->chunk($chunk_count)->map(function($chunk) {
    \DB::beginTransaction();

    // Create a record 
    $chunk->map(function($data) {
        StoreCommittee::create($data);
    });

    \DB::commit();
});
```